# I need help with an assignment question please for numerical methods

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

Consider the function $f (x) = xe^x - 2,$ we want to study the properties of $f (x)$ so that we can apply numerical methods to solve the equation $f (x) = 0$.

Which option is false ?

1. the function, $f (x)$ is well defined and continuous for all $x$ in the interval $(0,2)$
2. the function, $f (x)$ has no discontinuity and no singularities
3. the function, $f '(x)$ is well defined and continuous for all $x$ in the interval $(0,2)$
4. the function, $f '(x)$ has no discontinuity and no singularities
5. all of the above

I do not understand the different options given. How do I know if the function is well defined?

Comment: "Well-defined", in this context, just means, if you plug in a value of $x$, you get a value of $f$.

Comment: Given any $x\in (0,2)$, is there a number $f(x)$ defined without ambiguity? If so, the function is well-defined on $(0,2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Here is a plot of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ over the range (do they look [*continuous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) over the range, see any [*singularities*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_singularity) over $\mathbb{R}$). Can you make an analytical argument over the range $(0,2)$ and $\mathbb{R}$, respectively, regarding continuity and singularities? Are both continuous? Do either of them have singularities?

[image]

**Hint 2**: Here is a plot of $f(x) = 0$.

[image]

**Hint 3**: From hint 2, did you try solving $f(x) = 0$ analytically? Can you?

Comment: @Dee: Are you sure you wrote the function correctly in the problem? Regards

Comment: Ok, looking at the graph, it seems like it is continuous. I'm not sure what singularity means, sorry.

Comment: What if you had $1/(x-1)$. Where is the discontinuity? Where is the singularity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_singularity)?

Comment: @Dee: Did this resolve your issues?

Comment: Great (gr)hints, great graphs!  ;-) Needs a TU +

Comment: Hi there, sorry for late reply. I still need to research some more to be able to understand what is asked and what you are explaining. I've typed the question exactly as it is asked and we were not notified of any errors in the question yet.